# why innodb generate table-lock when two sql using different index?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

I know innodb-engine row lock by add lock to index item. But I don't understand the following scene.

Prepare sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_order`;
CREATE TABLE tbl_order (
    `order_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    `product_name` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    KEY `order_id_idx`(`order_id`),
    KEY `product_name_idx`(`product_name`)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO tbl_order(`order_id`, `product_name`) VALUES(1, 'prod1'), (2, 'prod2');
```

Session-1 execute sql:

```
SET autocommit=0;
SELECT @@autocommit;
SELECT `order_id`, `product_name` FROM tbl_order WHERE order_id=1 FOR UPDATE;
```

Session-2 execute sql:

```
SET autocommit=0;
SELECT @@autocommit;
SELECT `order_id`, `product_name` FROM tbl_order WHERE product_name='prod1' FOR UPDATE;
```

I know session-1 use order_id_idx index item, session-2 use product_naem_idx index item. I don't understand why session-1 blocks session-2.
The locks information:
[image]

The GEN_CLUST_INDEX indicates innodb use table-lock.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: If a record can be updated by both statements (`order_id=1` and `product_nema='prod1'`) than this is logical.

Comment: I don't know the details around InnoDB looking, but clearly it has to lock something besides the index entries. Your scenario would otherwise cause a lost update. I had a quick glance at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html but I can't tell from there how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

Every InnoDB table should be given an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  It must be "unique" and can either be a column (or combination of columns) or can be an `AUTO_INCREMENT` surrogate.

`GEN_CLUSTER_INDEX` is the fallback when you don't provide a PK.

`VALUES(1, 'prod1')` -- You are locking the *one row* from two different approaches (the secondary indexes).  Hence, it is quite proper to have a lock.  This lock will either lead to delaying one of the transactions until the other finished, or lead to a deadlock which will abort (and rollback) one of the transactions.

I don't believe you getting a "table lock", but instead a "row lock".

If your table is a "many-to-many" mapping table, please follow the advice in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: I found a answer on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html. As you said, my table don't have explicit primary key(cluster index). The InnoDB find cluster index(GEN_CLUST_INDEX) of secondary index and lock it when I execute first sql.Second sql is the same.Index order_id_idx and product_name_idx are secondary. So two sql use same cluster index lock. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @study_20160808 - I think your understanding is correct.  InnoDB must lock the row; the way to do that is via the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is, in your case, the `GEN_CLUST_INDEX`.